# cmd response 0x900, card status 0xb00

Tags: raspbian

I had to force shutdown the system as the system was getting hang. When i tried restarting it it showed  cmd response 0x900, card status 0xb00 error.
What is the possible solution? This was my first day with RPi.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your SD Card is compatible with Raspberry Pi, if it's not replace it. You can find out more about it on the [eLinux SD cards](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards) page, but basically just check the list to see if anyone else has had problems with your card.